# Do an action (purge in another server) after purging varnish

Tags: caching, varnish

I've two varnish, that one of them use ram as backend and another file as backend, requests first come to varnish(ram) and then go to another server in varnish(file) and then go to nginx, this is my diagram:

`Req=====> [varnish ram] =======> [varnish file] =====> [Nginx]`

Now i want to just purge a url in varnish ram for once and varnish ram automatically purge that url in varnish file,
Actually, i want to remove a file in varnish ram with purge and automatically that file or url will become remove in varnish file

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This not possible with the open source version.
You will need the broadcaster by Varnish-Software: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-broadcaster/usage/

Comment: I dont use varnish Plus and its not free,
How can i do this?
is there any free softwere or tricks for doing it?

Comment: Do you have IP's of both servers? Create a API that calls the IP's sequentially and purges the routes. If you got multiple load balancers at each level, you can use multiprocessing to efficiently hit the IP's directly.